# Swift macOS notification no sound

Tags: swift, macos

Somehow the notification that each time the program requested will be no sound. My MacBook is not in DND mode.

```swift
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

func sendNotification(title: String, body: String = "") {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    
    if body.count > 0 {
        content.body = body
    }
    
    // you can alse add a subtitle
    content.subtitle = "subtitle here... "
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(
        identifier: uuidString,
        content: content, trigger: nil)
    
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { _, _ in }
    notificationCenter.add(request)
}
```

Not in DND mode. Do not know what else steps that I could try.

Comment: What are the system prefs settings for the app?

Comment: @Willeke The sound for the app is allowed in my system prefs.